# Embedding image logo at the right of a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have the following logo and I want to embed it on my Shiny app at the right. I've trying some code from stackoverflow and I can't.

[image]

I want the logo and a link to a particular site, my app wants lo look like this:

[image]

My app starts like this:

```
ui <- navbarPage(
  theme = "estilo_bdd.css",
   "Observatorio de Movilidad, Infancia y Familia",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Encuesta Continua de Hogares",
    value = 'borelito',
    tabsetPanel(
      type = "pills",
      id   = "tabset",
      tabPanel(
        "Caracterización sociodemográfica",
        br(),
        sidebarPanel(
          style = "position:fixed;width:30%;",
          selectInput(
            "indicador_csd",
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for this.  You may need to adjust margin and padding.

```
ui <- navbarPage(
  tags$li(div(img(src = 'YBS.png', title = "A Test", height = "30px"),
              style = "margin-left:1100px; margin-top:-25px; padding-top:-50px; padding-right:10px;"),
          class = "dropdown")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```